# Store HiddenField Value

Tags: jquery, arrays, html

I have a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="POSITION[]"  id="hfPRData" runat="server"/>
```

Getting HiddenfEild Vlaue from server side that is

```
hfPRData.value = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

i want to store this value in source variable like

```
<script>
$('#myinput').tokenizer
 ({
     source: $('input[type="hidden"][name="POSITION[]"]').map(function () {
         debugger;
         return this.getAttribute("value");
     }).get() });
    </script>
```

How to Get hidden type value in var source ??

Comment: In hidden field you can store Array. `hfPRData.value = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']`  it is wrong assignment.

Comment: could you pass event to the function and get the value from there by using event.target.

Comment: you can get values using `$(this).val()` in place of `this.getAttribute("value")`